# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, transactions, relationship

so i am trying to set two related object in each other's fields. But when i debug the code i get that after i set the first object as a field in the other i am getting the following error: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method.

Here is the source code, i hope someone can help. Thank you :D

```
@Service @Transactional
public class MainService {

    @Autowired CustomTableRepository tRepo;
    @Autowired UserRepository uRepo;
    @Autowired ReservationRepository rRepo;

    @SneakyThrows
    public void reserveTable(Reservation reservation) {
        CustomTable table = tRepo.findById(reservation.getTable().getId()).get();
        User user = uRepo.findByUsername(reservation.getUser().getUsername());
        Reservation myReservation = new Reservation(null, reservation.getAccepted(), user, table, reservation.getTime());
        rRepo.saveAndFlush(myReservation);
        if(!(reservationRequirements(rRepo.findByUser(user))))
            throw new Exception("something went wrong with the reservation, regarding the requierements");
        else {
            user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - CONSTANTS.fee );
            user.setReservation(myReservation);
            myReservation.setAccepted(true);
            myReservation.setTable(table);
            myReservation.setUser(user);
            table.setReservation(myReservation);
            table.setAvailable(false);
            uRepo.saveAndFlush(user);
            tRepo.saveAndFlush(table);
            rRepo.save(myReservation);
        }
    }
    
    
    /*
     * PRIVATE HELPING METHODS
     */
    
    private Boolean reservationRequirements(Reservation reservation) {
        User user = uRepo.findByUsername(reservation.getUser().getUsername());
        //check if the user has enough money
        if(user.getBalance() < CONSTANTS.fee)
            return false;
        //check if they accepted the money fee.
        if(reservation.getAccepted() == false)
            return false;
        //if the table is occupied
        if(reservation.getTable().getAvailable() == null) {
            
        }else {
            if(reservation.getTable().getAvailable() == false)
                return false;
        }
        LocalTime time = CONSTANTS.parseLocalTime(reservation.getTime());
        if(!(time.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("07:30")) && time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("22:00"))))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is how they are all related one to other:

Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Boolean available;
    private Boolean busy;
    private Boolean arrived;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "table", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Reservation reservation;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Reservation {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private Boolean accepted;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_id")
    private CustomTable table;
    private String time;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String type;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Long number;
    private Long balance;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Reservation reservation;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

Thank you a lot for reading.

Comment: Btw i am also in an endless loop because of the relations of the user-reservation-table

Comment: For your Exception: I could only point 1 thing. are you getting the exception after this :  `rRepo.saveAndFlush(myReservation);`
If yes, then you should not flush the data. try saving the data without flushing.